# Retina Display favicon support?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, favicon

I recently noticed that all Stack Exchange sites have some pixelated favicons.

[image]

As you can see, Gmail has support for Retina Display favicons, while Twitter and SE sites do not.  It looks worse with the graduated sites.

[image]

I did notice that the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ and the rest of the top bar does seem to have support for Retina Displays though.

[image]

This is kind of a nitpick of a feature request, but could SE add some higher resolution favicons to stay consistent with the new StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™?

Comment: I think they did it now, can you confirm please? No retina for me.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It looks like they have done it.